# How to select specific position values inside an arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist

I need to get a **specific value** but I don't know how to get it without getting the entire value stored inside the `ArrayList`.

For example, the patient's stores this info: `Name`, `id`, `address`, these are stored trough the object `pa_datos`(an instance from `Persona class` using a constructor
       `paciente` `public void paciente(String _nombre,String _rut, String _ direccion,String _tipo_sangre)`.

Now I just need to get the name, but instead, I'm getting the entire info (name, id, address) etc.

```
 ArrayList<String> ficha = new ArrayList<>();

 ficha.add("Paciente: "+pa_datos.nombre+'\n'+'\n'
             +"Rut: "+pa_datos.rut+'\n'+'\n'
             +"Dirección: "+pa_datos.direccion+'\n'+'\n'
             +"Tipo de sangre: "+pa_datos.tipo_sangre+'\n'+'\n');

 for (String i :ficha) {
   System.out.println(i);
 }
```

Comment: What is your ArrayList of? Strings?

Comment: To store a patient's name, ID and address, you shouldn't use a list containing a single string. You should use a Patient class, with 3 properties: name, id and address. A list is useful to store multiple instances of the same thing. For example, if you want to store all the patients of a doctor for one day, you could store them in a List<Patient>.

Comment: I'm confused. Don't you already *HAVE* the name, in `pa_datos.nombre`?  Please elaborate your answer: show us the code for `pa_datos` (a class?), the code for `ficha` (ArrayList<String>?) and explain what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like

```
for (String i :ficha) { 
    String lines[] = i.split("\\r?\\n");
    System.out.println(lines[0]);
}
```